# Setting a bool if a string is present

Tags: c++

I need to set a boolean based on whether a string is present in my data dictionary, with a structure of:

```
std::map< string, foo > dd
```

If the string I'm looking for is there, then the boolean is true, and vice versa.  Can someone help me with how do I do this in C++?

Thanks.

Comment: What data structure are you using for your dictionary?

Comment: @NomNomNom: You should update the question rather than adding extra information as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose data dictionary is std::map< string, foo > dict;

```
bool const word_present( string str_word, std::map< string, foo > &dict)
{
    return (dict.find( str_word ) != dict.end());
}
```

Comment: I think using dict.count( str_word ) > 0 would be better

Comment: @Charles: it won't, why? It might be even worse for multi-map, as you need a first occurrence only and don't have to count all of them.

Comment: @Harry Seward: I saw that after I wrote a comment :-) Already deleted. Sorry.

Comment: @VladLazarenko They both operate at the same algo complexity.  I just find count > 0 makes more sense then building an iterator and checking against another iterator.  Agreed that with a multimap its a different story, but not here.

Comment: @Charles, @Vlad: let's refute the performance argument would you. Semantically, `find` is the natural way to express this while `count` is an indirect way. Write code that makes sense first, optimize later (if needed).

Comment: someone edited my original code that used a c'tor initialization for a bool, and instead created a boolean function. Now, str_word is passed by value ( copied ), which even a C++ n00b knows is bad. So if you read this answer and use my solution, use the & operator and pass the string by reference.